# "Error in rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x)) : invalid 'length.out' value" while trying to subset data.frame.txt, where is the problem?

Tags: r, load, subset

I wanted to load specific data table that was in .txt form. Then I tried to subset but it didn't work and wrote me the error stated. Where could be the problem?

I didnt actually try anything to do with this. The problem is that I'm a beginner.

Comment: Please include a [mre] that contains the code you have used and an example of your data, such as the output of `dput(head(mydata))`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.